# Webpack fails rendering express import

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

**NodeJS/Express**: Webpack fails transpiling `src/server/app.js` to `dist/server/app.js`, after me adding `import express from 'express'` to the src-file (`src/server/app.js`).

---

The error messages look like:

```
ERROR in ./~/express/lib/request.js
```

in detail:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net'
 in '/Users/timo/Desktop/Eggs/node_modules/express/lib'
```

or

```
ERROR in ./~/express/lib/view.js
```

in detail:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'
 in '/Users/timo/Desktop/Eggs/node_modules/express/lib'
```

---

Do I have to *change* something in my **webpack.config.babel.js**-file?

here it is:

```
export default [
  {
    entry: './src/server/app.js',
    output: {
      path: './dist/server',
      filename: 'app.js'
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] }
      }]
    }
  },
    {
    entry: './src/client/app.js',
    output: {
      path: './dist/client',
      filename: 'app.js'
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] }
      }]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting the [`"node"` target](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target) for your server-side code:

```
{
  entry  : './src/server/app.js',
  target : 'node',
  ...
}
```

By default, Webpack will compile for usage in a web browser, which doesn't support a lot of modules that only make sense to run server-side (like `net` and `fs`).

Answer (score 0):

are you config [.babelrc](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/)?webpack1 has no query option in [module.loaders](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders).if the problem even occurs.you can delete `node_modules` and reinstall `npm install`.May be something you link some dependencies from global repository via `npm link`,I have met.